# Dynamic field values are save and update

Tags: django, django-models

I have created one model file where i have defined table and under the table i have created some fields like:-teacher(foreign key),id(primary key),title,location etc.
Now i have created one Django's API which saved data into the database.
The problem statement is that we don't know which field will be update and insert by the User.
Example:- if the first time i have saved the title filed into the database and then i want to save location.
How i can handle to save and update the location value without effecting the title.
For User interaction we are using angular1.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/)

Example

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(pre_save, sender="Your model name")
def custom_signal(sender, update_fields, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # your algorithms
```